# WPF Play sound on Timer tick - doesn't repeat sound

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, mediaelement

I've just started to built metronome application and but I encountered a trouble with playing a sample sound on timer tick. I set the timer tick, for example to call the method which play a sound in every 1 second. And then it appeared a problem that the sound is played only one time and nothing more.

So, my question - How to do that to play sound in every timer tick?

```
  <Window x:Class="Metronome.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBox Name="textBox1" /> 
        <Button Name="button1" Content="Start" Click="button1_Click" />
        <MediaElement Name="mediaElement1" Source="MetroBar1.wav" LoadedBehavior="Manual" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
      using System.Collections.Generic;
      using System.Linq;
      using System.Text;
      using System.Windows;
      using System.Windows.Controls;
      using System.Windows.Data;
      using System.Windows.Documents;
      using System.Windows.Input;
      using System.Windows.Media;
      using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
      using System.Windows.Navigation;
      using System.Windows.Shapes;
      using System.Windows.Threading;

      namespace Metronome
 {
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    const int secInMin = 60;
    int beatRate;
    double beatPerMsec;

    DispatcherTimer timer1;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer1 = new DispatcherTimer();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //beatRate = Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
        //beatPerMsec = Math.Pow((beatRate / secInMin), -1) * 1000;   //Amount of beats (timer ticks) per msec
       // timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(metronome_Run);
        timer1.Tick += metronome_Run;
        //timer1.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, Convert.ToInt16(beatPerMsec));
        timer1.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void metronome_Run(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mediaElement1.Play();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: why do you write Math.Pow(a / b, -1) instead of b / a? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MSDN:

[`MediaElement.Play()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.play(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Plays media from the current position.

`MediaElement` doesn't reset its position automatically after it is done playing. You need to reset `Position` back to the beginning manually before calling `Play`.

```
private void metronome_Run(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mediaElement1.Position = new TimeSpan(0);
    mediaElement1.Play();
}
```

---

It might be safer to call [`Stop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.stop(v=vs.110).aspx) before calling `Play`, depending on the length of your sound file. `Stop` will automatically reset back to the beginning, and interrupt any currently playing sound.

```
private void metronome_Run(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mediaElement1.Stop();
    mediaElement1.Play();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes seconds way seems to be better because when I use mediaElement.Position I can hear that the beat is unstable.